# Number of full month (none partial) between 2 dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date

How to calculate full month(s) (none partial) between two dates in SQL? The results should be as follows:

> Start Date | End Date | Full Month 
>    5/02/2015 | 6/29/2015 | 0 
>   5/01/2015 | 6/30/2015 | 2 
>  
>   5/01/2015 | 6/05/2015 | 1 
>   5/31/2015 | 6/30/2015 | 1 
>  2/01/2015 | 2/28/2015 | 1 
>  2/27/2015 | 3/30/2015 | 0 
>  2/27/2015 | 3/31/2015 | 1

My code so far:

```
Select startDate [Start Date],
endDate [End Date],
DATEDIFF(MM,startDate,endDate) + CASE
    WHEN DAY(endDate) =DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,endDate),0)))
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0  
END - CASE
    WHEN DAY(startDate) = 1  
    THEN 0  
    ELSE 1  
END [Full Month]
FROM table
```

I need to use this within another multi-level nested CASE statement, so **looking to avoid the additional CASE statements**, if possible.

Additional Details:

I'm writing reports for third party software, not always the same RDBMS, mostly older versions of MS SQL Server. Also would like code on the report itself and not to store in database.

Comment: The date functions differ slightly from one RDBMS to the next, so please specify which SQL database (and version) you are using.

Comment: What would the results be for 2/27 to 3/27, 3/28, 3/29, 3/30 and 3/31 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(mm,startDate,endDate)-1 + 
    IIF(EOMONTH(endDate)=endDate, 1, 0) + 
    IIF(1=DAY(startDate), 1, 0)
AS full_months FROM dates;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be17e/14

or

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be17e/3 (MSSQL Server 2008)

Comment: Your code has a good idea on how to determine the end of month (MS SQL Server 2012 +). Otherwise it's the same as the code in the question, and does not answer how to avoid the Case statements.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what he meant, thought he didn't want to use any additional case statements than what he already had in his answer, just updated to avoid case statements

Comment: + 1. Good answer (MS SQL Server 2012 +). Still waiting to see if there is a good idea for older versions.